# $stateParams data null after switching states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, switching

I'm having an issue with using `$stateParams` to save user information after someone logs into my application. I have some login code that does a POST to Express, uses passport to authenticate, and once authentication is complete, send the user back as part of the response, and go to the dashboard state.

Login code:

```
User.login = function(user) {
        var defer = $q.defer();         

        $http.post('/login', user)
        .success(function(authenticatedUser) {

            if(authenticatedUser.redirect && authenticatedUser.username) {                  

                $state.go('app.dashboard.main', {userInformation: authenticatedUser});  
                var cookie = Cookie.getSessionCookie();                 

                defer.resolve(authenticatedUser);
            }           

        }, function(err, status) {              
            defer.reject(err);
        });

        return defer.promise;

    };
```

Server side (passport code omitted, it sends me back the user object from the database):

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.user) { //req.user holds the returned session object from the local strategy authentication
        console.log('authentication success');      

        var username  = req.user.username;
        var firstname = req.user.first_name;
        var lastname  = req.user.last_name;
        var userID    = req.user.id;

        var user = {
            username: username,
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname
        };                      

        res.cookie('user', user, { httpOnly: false, maxAge: 40000 }); //need to set HTTP only to false in order for client to access server side cookie

        res.json({
            redirect: true,         
            username: username,
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname 
        });
    }   
});
```

My dashboard code:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var DashboardCtrl = function($rootScope, $q, $http, User, userInformation, $stateParams) {

    this.user = userInformation;
    this.logout = User.logout;
};

angular
    .module('dashboard', [])

    .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            //child state of 'app'
            .state('app.dashboard', {
                url: '/dashboard',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'modules/dashboard/dashboard-scaffolding.html',
                data: {
                    //will apply to all children of 'dashboard'
                    requireLogin: true
                }                   
            })
            .state('app.dashboard.main', {
                url: '/main',
                params: {'userInformation': null},
                resolve: {
                    userInformation: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {                                              
                        return $stateParams.userInformation;
                    }]
                },
                templateUrl: 'modules/dashboard/dashboard-main.html',
                controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'dashboard'                       
            })          
    }]) 

    .directive('dashboardBody', function() {
        return {
            scope: true,
            restrict: 'AE',
            templateUrl: 'modules/dashboard/directives/dashboard-body-directive.html',
            replace: true
        }
    })

    .controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$http', 'User', 'userInformation', '$stateParams', DashboardCtrl]);


})();
```

When I land on the dashboard, I am using this code, and I see the username:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">                     
        <h1>Welcome, {{dashboard.user.username}}!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Part of my navigation HTML (when I click on profile, and then back on Home, the username disappears):

```
<nav class="dashboard navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="project-title">
                    <p><a ui-sref="app.dashboard.main">Home</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="right clearfix">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="" class="btn" ui-sref="app.dashboard.profile">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a class="btn" href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Does `$stateParams` get 'reset' everytime a state changes? When I return back to home, the value for `$stateParams` is `null`. I'd rather store the user's basic information here than use a service to do a database query each time I change states. Is this the best place to store user information anyway? Should I always be making a database query to grab it? Or store it in the session? Not sure here.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I am fairly certain that the `stateParams` are just that - params for the current state. This is not really the place to store "state" or "session" details. You _should_ use a service for that - not sure why you are against that. A service is the best place to store persistent data that you wish to share.

Comment: Yep, thanks Tim, not sure why I was suggesting against that. I've changed my code to use a service to store data in my top level module configuration, as trying to store persistent data between states wasn't very helpful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stateparams are URL parameters. Since none of your URLs is maintaining any values at all, the value of $stateParams would always come out to be null for you. Stateparams usually mean you need them to maintain a state of a particular web application.

For better understanding, you can actually refer to this link:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

form the url containing useful information, which may be necessary to navigate to a praticular state, such as user ID. for example, change url to something like, "/user/:userId". In reality, the same may become something like "/user/235462aed". Now, the stateparams would be something like:

```
$stateparams={   userId: '235462aed' }
```

and you can resolve the same before navigating to the state.

Comment: Thanks Shivi, this is helpful. I've changed my code around to use a service to store user information instead of going through the trouble to use $stateParams, because as you mentioned, they will be null once the states change, and that isn't helpful for persistent information :)